# SQL copy table with the same name problem

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I have two same databases with same table names but one of them have more data inside. How do I copy all data from one table to another database and in the table with the same name? I keep getting some foreign key problem when trying to export/import data. Some of the data inside tables are the same.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do a direct copy if they've got the same name. So you've got a number of options:

1. You say ONE of them has more data, copy this one separately and give a different name.
2. Create tmp tables of the tables you're copying in the database you're copying from and copy these instead
3. Change the names of the tables in the database you're copying to.
4. Create a new schema and put them in there.
5. If the data in the database you're copying to is a subset of the data in the database you're copying from AND the database you're copying to is not a production server then you can trash it, i.e. drop everything and start again with the new data.
6. Drop the foreign key and re-create it at the other end. No data is going to be added while the table is in transit.

There'll be more...